# How to improve below method logic?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, java-ee-7

I am using JAVA7. I have below method.

```
public static <T extends BaseClass> T newObject(Class<T> classOfT, String someName)
    {

        SomeClass data = new SomeClass();
        data.setName(someName);

        Class[] constructorSignature = new Class[] {SomeClass.class};
        Object[] constructorArgs = new Object[] {data};


        return returnNewObject(classOfT, constructorSignature, constructorArgs);
    }
```

Now i have to write a generic method which will accept above parameters. Method should be generic.

```
private static <T extends BaseClass> T returnNewObject(Class<T> classOfT, Class[] constructorSignature, Object[] constructorArgs) throws SomeException
    {

        try
        {

            Constructor<T> domainObjectConstructor = classOfT.getDeclaredConstructor(constructorSignature);
            return (T)domainObjectConstructor.newInstance(constructorArgs);
        }
}
```

Now how can i avoid below two lines?

```
Class[] constructorSignature = new Class[] {SomeClass.class};
            Object[] constructorArgs = new Object[] {data};
```

I simply took arrays of **Class** and **Object** just to make the **returnNewObject** method generic.

Now how can i avoid above arrays and still make the **returnNewObject** method generic?

**returnNewObject** method should take any class, any data and any class type to copy the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this.

```
public static <T extends BaseClass> T newObject(Class<T> classOfT, String someName) {
    try {
        return classOfT.getConstructor(SomeClass.class)
                       .newInstance(new SomeClass(someName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
         throw new SomeException("Failed to create " + classOfT, e);
    }
}
```

You returnNewObject doesn't add much value, it just complicates things.

---

What you could do if you have just one argument is

```
private static <T extends BaseClass> T returnNewObject(Class<T> classOfT, Object arg) throws SomeException {
    try {
        return (T) classOfT.getConstructor(arg.getClass()).newInstance(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Peter, thnx for ur reply. the reason why i created returnNewObject method is, now i have SomeClass.class and i can also have SomeOtherClass.class. So to deal with any class and any data i have written returnNewObject method. Could u plz give me idea? Thanx!

Comment: @user755806 if you want to simplify the code, try to not make it more generic than it needs to be.